# On the nature of a submanifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

In the book "Topology from the Differential Viewpoint" (Milnor) on page 11 we get the following lemma:

> If $f: M\to N$ is a smooth map between manifolds of dimension $m\geq n$ and if $y\in N$ is a regular value, then the set $f^{-1}(y) \subset M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $m-n$.

My question is:

What are the conditions on the function $f$ to get:

a) $f^{-1}(y)$ is connected

b) $f^{-1}(y)$ is simply connected  or Non-simply connected

c) $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite

d) $f^{-1}(y)$ is infinite

For example we know that $S²$ is simply connected and related to a well known function.

Comment: It is too difficult to just answer your questions. Have you see some examples of such submanifolds?

Comment: @edm: We know that $S²$ is simply connected and related to a well known function.

Comment: c) and d) are easy to answer. Due to local homeomorphism to $\Bbb R^{m-n}$, submanifolds are usually infinite.

Comment: I would say the question a) and b) are extremely ill-posed in general; This is not what one can hope to answer from Morse theory. Actually you can even show that any map $f$ with $f^{-1}(y)$ connected can be perturbed a bit away from $f^{-1}(y)$ so that the preimage of $y$ of the perturbed map is $f^{-1}(y)$ disjoint union with some nontrivial subset of $M$, and by moving $y$ across some critical points to make the preimage another manifold cobordant to $f^{-1}(y)$, which is usually not simply connected even if $f^{-1}(y)$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer for $(c)$:

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds (of the same dimension), with $M$ compact, and let $f : M \to N$ be a smooth map, with $y \in N$ a regular value for $f$, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is a finite set.

*Proof:* Since $\{y\} \subseteq N$ is closed, and $f$ is smooth (and hence continuous), it follows that $f^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is closed in $M$.

Now suppose $f^{-1}(y)$ was not finite (and hence infinite), then $f^{-1}(y)$ would contain a limit point, say $p \in f^{-1}(y)$ since $M$ is compact (because infinite subsets of compact sets contains a limit point). The fact that $p$ is contained in $f^{-1}(y)$ follows from the fact that $f^{-1}(y)$ is closed in $M$. Since $p$ is a limit point of $f^{-1}(y)$, by definition every neighbourhood of $p$ contains at least one point, say $q$, in $f^{-1}(y)$  other than itself.

Now $f(q) = y$, which contradicts the inverse function theorem which says that $f$ is one-to-one in some neighbourhood $U'$ of each $x \in f^{-1}(y)$. Hence $f^{-1}(y)$ must be finite. $\square$

**Edit**: Look at page 8 of Milnor's book, which is where he claims this.

---

Answer for $(d)$

If $f : M \to N$ is a smooth map between manifolds of dimension $m > n$, and if $y \in N$ is a regular value, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is infinite

*Proof:* Suppose $f^{-1}(y)$ was finite, then every neighbourhood $U \subseteq M \cap f^{-1}(y)$ of $x \in f^{-1}(y)$ contains only finitely many points. But since $f^{-1}(y)$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $m -n \geq 1$, some neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ must be homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m-n}$. But any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m-n \geq 1}$ contains infinitely many points and since homeomorphims are bijective, we have a bijection between a finite set (namely $V$) and an infinite set, a direct contradiction. $ \square$

Comment: @BalarkaSen pointed this out to me, so credit should go to him for this part of the answer as well.

Comment: Be careful with $n=m$ case! See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, in general you cannot claim anything about a) and b) for a random $f$.

However, for c nd d we have this: When $n=m$, by being a regular point we can show that the set $f^{-1}\{y\}$ cannot have accumulation point. In other words it is a discrete set. Because of this, if the domain is bounded, then this set must be finite. If the domain is unbounded then this set can be either finite or countably large.